# Unable to select Bluemix Organization when attempting to publish API Connect product/API

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am new to API connect and I'm trying to create a simple loopback application and publish the product and API to bluemix.

Steps I've followed so far:-

On Bluemix:-

1. Added a API connect service to my organization ('subhash.pesh@gmail.com'), US South region and and test space.
2. Default Sandbox catalog created in APIConnect.

On Local machine:-

1. Got the APIC CLI
2. Created a loopback app by running: apic loopback
3. Ran the API designer by using apic edit
4. Express server started listening in on a port and the GUI editor opened up in my default browser.
5. Tried to publish the product by adding a bluemix target.

Here is where I'm facing the issue:
I'm able to enter my bluemix credentials and it chooses US South region by default, but I'm not able to see any organizations within the next dropdown.

I've tried doing this while the app is running locally and while it's stopped (I dont think it should make any difference, but I was getting desperate)

Ive attached the pictures of the publishing option/ empty organization dropdown here:-

[Organization dropdown can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UltcY.png)

[Unable to see any of my organizations, dropdown is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vzC2.png)

I'm sure I'm missing something vital, but I'm just not able to figure this out.
I've tried going through the documentations and video tutorials and by their account, I should be able to select the organizations and then the catalog to which I want to publish the API.

EDIT: I observed something while trying to publish from CLI:
After logging in to us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com, when I run

apic orgs --server us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com

I get a blank response.. Not sure why my bluemix organizations are not being recognized

And when I run

apic catalogs --all-organizations --server us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com

I get 
Error: No catalogs found in all organizations
Error: No catalogs found in org null

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the output from `apic --ext-version`

Comment: @Rick : Does this help?:-
apic --ext-version
apiconnect: v2.1.19 (API Connect: v5.0.2.1)
 apiconnect-cli-apis 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-apps 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-auth 2.1.6
 apiconnect-cli-catalogs 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-config 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-create 2.1.1
 apiconnect-cli-drafts 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-edit 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-loopback 2.1.3
 apiconnect-cli-orgs 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-pm 2.1.0
  microgateway 1.2.0
   flow-engine 1.0.3
 apiconnect-cli-policies 1.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-products 2.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-validate 2.1.0
 plugins 3.0.2

Comment: Also, I observed something just now while trying to publish from CLI:
After logging in to us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com, when I run 

apic orgs --server us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com,

 I get a blank response.. Not sure why my bluemix organizations are not being recognized

Comment: The first place I'd start is by installing an updated version of apiconnect.

Comment: @SUBHASHPESHWA are you still experiencing issues with the APIC CLI. Have you tried the suggestion of upgrading the version?